# Copied Subversion Repository is not updated in XCode anymore

Tags: svn, xcode

Recently I changed the repository directory to reside under a different location.
What I did was to basically copy the entire Subversion directory to the desired location (and rename the old one to test that it is indeed working) and then in the XCode change the Repository location to reflects the new location.

Ever since then, although I do see the correct repository through the repository window, the files in the XCode do not reflect their state and I do not have the repository right click menu items, so I guess that I forgot to change something else / erase some temporary files and so the connection is lost.

Any help would be appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the following:

Your working copy still contains subversion information pointing to the old repository, i.e. in the `.svn` directories. Try to re-checkout a working copy from the new repository and work on that with XCode. Be careful if you have made changes to the old working copy since moving the repo; the safest way will be to check out a working copy to a new directory (instead of using `svn switch` in the old one).

Note that I don't use XCode and thus don't know much about the integration of Subversion into it, but I can imagine that the above might be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Copying a directory on Macintosh deletes the old directory first and then copies the contents of the old directory into it. What this means is that you aren't getting a "merge" as you'd expect in Windows, and any svn subdirectories are being deleted out of the destination folder.

This is likely the cause of your problem.

Comment: As I understand it, Adi created a new directory anyway. Also, he/she copied the repository, not the working copy, so the destination directory shouldn't need to keep any previous content even if it had such.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys,

Indeed - having the Finder concealing the fact that I do have .svn folders, I neglected to check this out and these directories most likely contained the missing link.

Practically I used Chris' suggestion which solved most of my problem - since I had some changes already made from the submitted version, I copied the directory aside, totally checked out the directory from the repository and then rewrote the files I knew were changed (which is a bit risky, since I only noticed the broken link half a day late).

In any case, this worked like a charm for me and so - the entire process is:

In addition to setting all the path correctly in the **SCM->Repositories** in the XCode environment, one also needs to do the 'project checkout' operation again in order to correct the local .svn tags and restore the link to the XCode.

-Adi